# regex - replace 3rd dot and space with line break

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression below that works fine. What it does is it looks for every 3rd "." and inserts a break line...

```
some_string.replace(/((?:\.[^\.]*){2})\./g, '$1\.<br/><br/>')
```

so this text:

```
some test. some other test. other 2 test. test nice text.
```

becomes:

```
some test. some other test. other 2 test.  
test nice text.
```

I need to change this to look for a dot and space too. In other words, currently:

```
some test. some other test. other 2.3 test. test nice text.
```

will look like:

```
some test. some other test. other 2.
3 test. test nice text.
```

and I need this text to look like this:

```
some test. some other test. other 2.3 test. 
test nice text.
```

Comment: You can use: `some_string.replace(/((?:\.[^.]*){2})\. /, '$1\.<br/><br/>')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
replace(/(([^.]|\.(?! ))*\. ){3}/g, '$&<br/><br/>')
```

## Explanation

```
/([^.]|\.(?! ))*\. /
```

This matches a **non** `.` character (`/[^.]/`) or `.` character that is **not** followed by a space (`/\.(?! )/`). It continues matching (`/*/`) until it encounters a `.` followed by a space (in this case both `/[^.]/` and `/\.(?! )/` don't match, thus continuing to `/\. /`).

The reason I use a negative look ahead `/(?! )/` is because I want to evaluate this character by character. If I where to replace it with `/[^ ]/` than it would also match the "not a space" character. This means that if I end a line with two dots `Test sentence.. Test 2.` it would **not** match `Test sentence..<space>` because the second dot is included in the `/\.[^ ]/`, thus already passed by.

The `/{3}/` makes sure that the group matches 3 times.

`'$&<br/><br/>'` Will replace the entire match with itself followed by 2 line breaks.

#### Note

I'm using capture groups although I'm not using them. If you like to use non capture groups you can safely replace all capture groups with non capture groups.

#### Edit

For a more readable solution see [ctwheels answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436203/regex-replace-3rd-dot-and-space-with-line-break/47438447#answer-47439287). This does exactly the same, but uses a lazy solution. Keep in mind that lazy regex is often a bit slower when used on large text (I haven't tested the speed of both). But if readability is more important I would go for his solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overcomplicating the RegEx, you could use a little known feature of `.replace` in javascript.

It's second argument can be a function as well, instead of a string.
For the full documentation on this look here:
[Funtion as second parameter to `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

For a working example for your problem try this:

```
let i = 0
some_string.replace(/\. /g, () => {
    return i++ == 2 ? '. <br /><br />' : '. '
})
```

*If you are unfamiliar with arrow functions (the `() => {}` thing), you can [read about them here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions),

or in case you do not know what `a ? b : c` means, it's the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).*

It does the job perfectly for your given examples as you can see in this demo:

```js
const break_lines = (some_string) => {
  let i = 0
  return some_string.replace(/\. /g, () => {
    return i++ == 2 ? '. <br />' : '. '
  })
}

const texts = [
  'some test. some other test. other 2 test. test nice text.',
  'some test. some other test. other 2.3 test. test nice text.'
]

for (const text of texts) {
  document.body.innerHTML += `${text}<br /> --> <br />${break_lines(text)}<br /><br />`
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Consolas;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Brief

For viewing purposes, I've used the replacement of `$1\n`. In reality, you would change this to `$1<br/><br/>` (`$&<br/><br/>` with the edit).

---

### Code

#### Original

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/e63rJQ/1)

```
((?:.*?\. ){2}.*?)\.
```

**Note**: There's a space at the end of the pattern above.

#### Edit

Thanks to [Johan Wentholt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3982562/johan-wentholt) for the edit below.

```
(.*?\. ){3}
```

Replacement

```
$&\n
```

#### Usage

```js
var s = [
  "some test. some other test. other 2 test. test nice text.",
  "some test. some other test. other 2.3 test. test nice text."
];

s.forEach(function(e) {
  var x = e.replace(/(.*?\. ){3}/g, "$&\n");
  console.log(x);
});
```

---

### Explanation

- `((?:.*?\. ){2}.*?)` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `(?:.*?\. ){2}` Match the following exactly twice

    - `.*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible
    - `\.` Match the dot character `.` literally, followed by the space character  literally
  - `.*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible
- `\.` Match the dot character `.` literally, followed by the space character  literally

Comment: Nice find, it removes the `.<space>` of the last sentence of 3 though. I would change the regex to `replace(/(.*?\. ){3}/g, "$&\n")` this makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: @JohanWentholt thanks for the catch! I've edited my answer to include your code (and give proper credit)

Answer (score 0):

All of those are for dot and spaces, I keep my snippets just in case:

```
/^(\s{0,1}\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space ..hello space')
false
/^(\s{0,1}\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space .hello space')
true
v2:

/^(\s?\.?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space .hello space')
true
/^(\s?\.?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space ..hello space')
false
v3: if you need some thisn like one space or dot between

/^([\s\.]?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space hello space')
true
/^([\s\.]?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space.hello space')
true
/^([\s\.]?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space .hello space')
false
v4:

/^([ \.]?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space hello space')
true
/^([ \.]?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space.hello space')
true
/^([ \.]?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space .hello space')
false
/^([ ]?\.?[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('space .hello space')
true
```

If you want to test them with your regex i'd recommend [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add \s ? Like this:

```
(/((?:\.[^\.]*){2})\.\s/g, '$1\.<br/><br/>')
```

Comment: This will count the dot in `2.3` as well and break the line after one less occurrences than expected.